# SQL output records with a single hashtag

Tags: sql

I have made a twitter like database with with one of the tables being tweets which has a tweetid, tweet itself, userid, and a timestamp.

Is there a way to query this table to output tweets with exactly one hashtag in the tweet.

I know I have to use LIKE "%#%" but that would return all tweets with hashtags. I want to output the tweets with only one hashtag in it.

Comment: Edit your question and show sample data and desired results.  Also, include the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do what you want:

```
select t.*
from tweets t
where t.tweet like '%#%' and
      t.tweet not like '%#%#%';
```

This looks for exactly one `'#'` in the tweet.

Answer (score 0):

How big is the table (number of rows), you could do the following, but performance wouldn't be great.

```
WHERE len(tweet)-len(replace(tweet,'#',''))=1
```

While this would work, I recommend Gordon's solution, although neither solution is going to offer great performance.

Answer (score 0):

You should really have your hashtags in a separate table related to your tweetID.

```
select * from tweets where tweetID in
(select tweetID from tweets group by tweetID having count(*)=1)
```

But if you're not going to alter the database structure then one of the others will have to do.